# swagger-codegen is not correctly generating common parameters for any language

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

According to the [swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/), I should be able to have common parameters that are shared by all operations. The problem is that when running codegen locally, the generated code does not have any of the **common path** parameters. The below `yaml` produces code for any language (I've tried two).

What is very confusing is that if I use this exact `yaml` in https://editor.swagger.io/, the generated code **does** have the path parameters. I ran this for two different languages, typescript:

[image]

And C#:

[image]

Left is the code generated in editor.swagger.io and right is my generated code by running codegen locally.

In both cases, the `.swagger-codegen\VERSION` the file is `3.0.20` which is the one I'm using but the code generated by https://editor.swagger.io/ does have the parameter paths.

This simple yaml file reproduces the issue:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
    title: title
    version: 1.0.0
paths:
    '/instances/{id}':
        summary: Manipulate a particular instance
        get:
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: Ok
                    content:
                        text/plain:
                          schema:
                            type: string
                            example: pong
            summary: Fetches an instance
        parameters:
            -   in: path
                name: id
                schema:
                    type: integer
                required: true
components:
    securitySchemes:
        bearerAuth:
            scheme: bearer
            bearerFormat: JWT
            type: http
```

The command line used for generation:

```
java   ^
    -classpath bin/swagger-codegen-cli.jar                                      ^
    -DdebugOperations                                                           ^
    io.swagger.codegen.v3.Codegen                                               ^
    generate                                                                    ^
    -i enterpos-api.yaml                                                        ^
    -l typescript-angular                                                       ^
    -o generated-code/typescript-angular-builtin
```

And that generated this output: https://gist.github.com/alanboy/45ce792255e079dd0de4f70449ebf455. I feel like this might be wrong usage or something wrong with my yaml but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: @Helen I did: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/10397  I ended up asking here because I wasn't getting any responses on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Main class. I noticed that using the `io.swagger.codegen.v3.Codegen` class produces incorrect results :

```
java -classpath bin/swagger-codegen-cli.jar  io.swagger.codegen.v3.Codegen  <more>
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But this works:

```
java -jar bin/swagger-codegen-cli.jar <more>
```

Which led me to open `MANIFEST.MF` in the jar and notice the main class is actually this:

```
Main-Class: io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen
```

I then ran the command like this and everything worked as expected.

```
java -classpath bin/swagger-codegen-cli.jar  io.swagger.codegen.v3.cli.SwaggerCodegen  <more>
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```